# how to use a single ajax process looped form

Tags: php, ajax

I have a HTML form that might be in a loop thus:

```
<form name="ajaxform" id="ajaxform<?php echo $sn;?>" action="" method="POST">
<p>Comment:<br /> <input type="text" value="" style="width:400px" name="comment<?php echo $sn;?>"     />    
<input type="button"  id="simple<?php echo $sn;?>" class="submit" value="Save" />

<div id="simple-msg<?php echo $sn;?>"></div>

</form>

<?php 
// the loop is ending here
?>
```

Now, the ajax code for posting these form onto a specific url is here:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{

$("#simple<?php echo $sn;?>").click(function()
{
$("#ajaxform<?php echo $sn;?>").submit(function(e)
{
//$('#simple').val().submit(function()
//$("#ajaxform1").submit(function(e)
//{
//$('#simple-msg').show();
    $("#simple-msg<?php echo $sn;?>").html("<img src='ajax/profile/ajax-loader.gif'/>");
    var postData = $(this).serializeArray();
    var formURL = $(this).attr("action");
    $.ajax(
    {
        url : "ajax/results/comment.php?id=<?php echo $sn;?>",
        type: "POST",
        data : postData,
        success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) 
        {
            $("#simple-msg<?php echo $sn;?>").html(''+data+'');

        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) 
        {
            $("#simple-msg<?php echo $sn;?>").html('<font color="red">Failed to save<br/>     textStatus='+textStatus+', errorThrown='+errorThrown+'</font><span class="icon icon-color icon-    close"></span>');
        }
    });
    e.preventDefault(); //STOP default action
    e.unbind();
});

$("#ajaxform<?php echo $sn;?>").submit(); //SUBMIT FORM
});


});
</script>
```

The problem is how do I use this ajax script to process all the form without having to loop the script too. as you can see in the script above, I want to remove all the(). if I do that and submit the form, only the first form process, but if I put the script in the loop, all will process. I figure that this is a bad practise as if I have a thousand form in a page, the script also repeat a thousand time. large data to the browser huh?

Answer (score 0):

Use classes:

```
<form name="ajaxform" action="" method="POST" data-sn="<?php echo $sn;?>">
<p>Comment:<br /> <input type="text" value="" style="width:400px" name="comment<?php echo $sn;?>"     />    
<input type="button" class="simple submit" value="Save" />

<div class="simple-msg"></div>

</form>
```

And JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".simple").click(function() {
    var $ajaxForm = $(this).parents('form');
    var $simpleMsg = $ajaxForm.find('simple-msg');
        $ajaxForm.submit(function(e) {
            $simpleMsg.html("<img src='ajax/profile/ajax-loader.gif'/>");
            var postData = $(this).serializeArray();
            var formURL = $(this).attr("action");
            $.ajax({
                url: "ajax/results/comment.php?id=" + $ajaxForm.data('sn'),
                type: "POST",
                data: postData,
                success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                    $simpleMsg.html('' + data + '');
                },
                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    $simpleMsg.html('<font color="red">Failed to save<br/>textStatus=' + textStatus + ', errorThrown=' + errorThrown + '</font><span class="icon icon-color icon-close"></span>');
                }
            });
            e.preventDefault(); //STOP default action
            e.unbind();
        });
        $ajaxForm.submit(); //SUBMIT FORM
    });

});
```

Comment: It allow you to use 1 script for several forms, if it's not your question, edit it to explain better. I try to help, be polite.

Comment: It will work if you replace [...] by your code and apply the same logic to all ids, I just have given to you the method. I will complete the code, but you must adapt it, put the JS out of the loop and replace ids by class in HTML code.

Comment: Note that I used data-sn to get $sn and pass it ir the AJAX URL.

Comment: its been long time anyway, since this thing cant still work, I i have settled to my old way...